# Excel VBA to run Access Macro---Linked Table issue

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Access query that creates a data table based on user defined parameters.
The data table is linked to excel, with a shared connection to Access.

I found some VBA code to run an Access macro from Excel, that basically reruns the query and updates the Access data table.

The issue i am having, is that I can't run the Excel VBA code with the Shared Connection, as it shows an error saying it is unable to delete the data in access, and therefore cannot complete the query.

The Excel VBA only works when the shared connection (linked Table) is removed.

How can I run an Access Macro from Excel using VBA, so that the access table is updated, and then the linked shared connection table in excel is refreshed and new data is shown?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! (1) When you say _data table_, do you mean a plain and simple _table_ or _base table_, as opposed to a _linked table_? Or is it _linked to excel_?   (2) I understand that the query **creates** the linked table; is this accurate? It might help if you include the query in your question (go to SQL View, and include the text there.)   (3) How do the _user-defined parameters_ affect the linked table?

Comment: @ZevSpitz The Data Table is just a plain table in Access, containing the filtered data based on parameters entered by a user in an access form.

Comment: @ZevSpitz (1) The Data Table is just a plain table in Access, containing the filtered data based on parameters entered by a user in an access form. This Data table is linked to Excel via a shared connection. I have no issues with the Access side as that is working. My objective is to allow the end user to run an Access Macro from Excel. The Access Macro, does a re-query and provides updated data to the shared connection table in Excel. The issue is I can't get this work because the Shared connection makes Access think it is being used, and therefore the macro wont run until I remove the connec

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand -- Where does the data reside? Does it reside only in an Excel spreadsheet? Only in an Access base table (i.e. not a linked table)? Or is there an Access base table which holds a copy of some of the records in the spreadsheet, to which the user initiates a fill, and at that point the user also specifies which records should be inserted into the Access table?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Sorry for confusion. I have in Access a primary data table, containing all customer quotes and information. I created an Access query to filter the data based on an Access Form, that users can enter parameters in. The end result is a table containing the filtered data in Access (Query1). In excel I have set up a shared connection between excel and Access which creates a table in excel with the data from the filtered access table (Query1). This table in excel is used to do more analysis.

Comment: @ZevSpitz the issue is that the user has to open Access, run the query, close Access, open the excel file and refresh the data. I would like to have a button in Excel, that runs the Access query and refreshes the linked table in excel to show the new data. I found some code which runs the access query, however it will only work when the shared connection is removed, but then the data in excel is not updated when refreshed. I get the error message "Could not delete from the specified tables."

Comment: Is it possible to break the shared connection, run the Access Query, reestablish the connection and refresh the excel linked table using VBA.